# Prediction over time using RNN

Tags: python, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

I have to predict Ethanol concentration over time (1hour… 16 hours).
I have 5 samples(A,B,C,D,E), 3 experiments (R1,R2,R3).

And 27 conditions(C11-1…).

I want to predict the value of ethanol over time using the RNN.
I have the train set and test set, but have no idea how to adapt RNN on my data.

I’ve tried some written algorithms but doesn’t succeed.

Expecting predicted value of Ethanol, for 1hour, 2hour… 16hour.

Select significant 5 conditions and do the ethanol’s prediction

Compare the R2

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.